# Jquery image gallery while loop

Tags: jquery, image, gallery

I can't seem to make these images loop and fade in/fade out to make an image gallery. Why is my code not working? I want the images and animation to dissapear after I stop hovering on button1.

```
$(".button1").hover(function(){

    $("#about").fadeOut(0);
    $(".button12").fadeOut(0);
    $("#frame").fadeIn(250);

    while (".button1".hover()){
     $("#image1").fadeIn(250);
     $("#image1").delay(6000).fadeOut(250);
     $("#image2").delay(6000).fadeIn(250);
     $("#image2").delay(12000).fadeOut(250);
     $("#image3").delay(12000).fadeIn(250);
     $("#image3").delay(18000).fadeOut(250);

     }


  });
```

Comment: please put this on jsfiddle including the html

Comment: you are doing wrong with while condition. that's not the way and why are you not placing the code in hover function all of the while condition

Comment: I think you want to call two functions on hover as per your comment so you should use like .hover(function_one, function_two);

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong `while (".button1".hover()){` I have changed your code like this,

```
         $('.button1').live('mouseover', function () {
             $("#about").fadeOut(0);
             $(".button12").fadeOut(0);
             $("#frame").fadeIn(250);
             $("#image1").fadeIn(250);
             $("#image1").delay(6000).fadeOut(250);
             $("#image2").delay(6000).fadeIn(250);
             $("#image2").delay(12000).fadeOut(250);
             $("#image3").delay(12000).fadeIn(250);
             $("#image3").delay(18000).fadeOut(250);
          });

          $('.button1').live('mouseleave', function () {
             $("#image1").fadeOut(0);
             $("#image2").fadeOut(0);
             $("#image3").fadeOut(0);
          });
```

Demo link http://jsfiddle.net/dhana36/753Lt/

Comment: i want to make the images and animation stop after i stop hovering button1, how do i do this?

Comment: @user3205630  Then edit your question and ask clearly

Comment: @dhana the code doesn't work at all now, it doesn't even show up